# Python/arduino serial communication issue

Tags: python, arduino, serial-port, communication, pyserial

I tried to light up one led on my Arduino nano with serial.
It works with the serial monitor in the IDE. When I use my python code  it lights up and turns immediately back off.

arduino code:

```
int ledPin = 13;

void setup()
{
  //Create Serial Object
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("<Arduino is ready>");
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  //Have the arduino wait to receive input
  while (Serial.available() == 0);
 // while (Serial.available());
  //Read the Input
  int val = Serial.read(); - '0';
  Serial.println(val);
  if (val == 1) 
  {
    Serial.println("Led is On"); 
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
  }
  else if (val == 0)
  {
    Serial.println("Led is Off");
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("Invalid!");
  }
  Serial.flush();

}
```

Python code:

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/serial/by-id/usb-1a86_USB2.0-Serial-if00-port0', 9600)
print(ser.name)
ser.write([1])
ser.close()
```

Comment: Did you try to put `time.sleep(5)` inbetween `ser.write() ` and `ser.close() `? Also you need to import the python module time

Comment: a new USB connection resets Uno/Nano/Mini/Mega and they spend some second in bootloader waiting for sketch upload. half of the Python/Arduino questions is about this